# ErrorHandler and Log

Tags: java, xml, logging, handler

I would like to write a log about a Java class which implements ErrorHandler. My class is used to handle the errors coming from the reading of an xml file.
I try my best looking on the website but I do not understand why this code is leaving the log files empty. 
Moreover I do not understand how to manage the logger in my application. What are the best practise? Do you suggest to have just one log file or more? I will have to log more than one errorhandler: do you suggest to put all the log code into is errorhandler class? Should I implement a logger for the hole app?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

class XmlErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger( XmlErrorHandler.class.getName() );

    FileHandler fileHandler;

    public XmlErrorHandler() {
        try {  

            fileHandler = new FileHandler("./xml.log");  
            LOGGER.addHandler(fileHandler);

            SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
            fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter);  


        } catch (SecurityException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }       
    }

    public void error(SAXParseException e) {
        log(Level.SEVERE, "Error", e);
    }

    public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) {
        log(Level.SEVERE, "Fatal Error", e);
    }

    public void warning(SAXParseException e) {
        log(Level.WARNING, "Warning", e);
    }

    private void log(Level level, String message, SAXParseException e) {
        int line = e.getLineNumber();
        int col = e.getColumnNumber();
        String publicId = e.getPublicId();
        String systemId = e.getSystemId();

        message = message + ": " + e.getMessage() + ": line=" + line + ", col=" + col + ", PUBLIC=" + publicId
                + ", SYSTEM=" + systemId;

        LOGGER.log(level, message);
    }

}
```

EDIT:
All I do to initialize the log is:

```
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
documentBuilder.setErrorHandler(new XmlErrorHandler());
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you invoking your log? I've copied your Class and works fine.

And then invoke this way:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        documentBuilder.setErrorHandler(xmlErrorHandler);

        File f = new File("bad.xml");         
        document = documentBuilder.parse(f);        
    }
```

The output:

```
jun 13, 2016 5:45:46 PM es.test.XmlErrorHandler log
INFORMACIÓN: message 1
jun 13, 2016 5:45:46 PM es.test.XmlErrorHandler log
GRAVE: message 2
jun 13, 2016 5:45:46 PM es.test.XmlErrorHandler log
ADVERTENCIA: message 3
```

To register the class as a Handler I do that:

```
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            documentBuilder.setErrorHandler(xmlErrorHandler);

            File f = new File("bad.xml");         
            document = documentBuilder.parse(f);
```

This writes the exception to the log file

Comment: I don't understand how the handler works. I though the handler will invoke the the log by itself when it handles an error. I put above the code

Comment: It certainly does. I edited my answer with an example that logs an exception. Maybe you should try to invoke first from a main method and when it works register as a Sax ErrorHandler. However what I would do is to create a Class for your Logger and another for your ErrorHandler and test them separately.